# Filter xarray ZARR dataset with GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, python-xarray, zarr

I am reading a ZARR file from a s3 bucket with xarray. I got to successfully filter by time and latitude/longitude:

```py
    def read_zarr(self, dataset: str, region: Region) -> Any:
        # Read ZARR from s3 bucket
        fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(key="KEY", secret="SECRET")
        mapper = fs.get_mapper(f"{self.S3_PATH}{dataset}")
        zarr_ds = xr.open_zarr(mapper, decode_times=True)

        # Filter by time
        time_period = pd.date_range("2013-01-01", "2023-01-31")
        zarr_ds = zarr_ds.sel(time=time_period)

        # Filter by latitude/longitude
        region_gdf = region.geo_data_frame
        latitude_slice = slice(region_gdf.bounds.miny[0], region_gdf.bounds.maxy[0])
        longitude_slice = slice(region_gdf.bounds.minx[0], region_gdf.bounds.maxx[0])
        return zarr_ds.sel(latitude=latitude_slice, longitude=longitude_slice)
```

The problem is that this returns a rectangle of data (actually a cuboid, if we consider the time dimension). For geographical regions that are long and thin, this will represent a huge waste, as I will first download years of data, to then discard most of it. Example with California:

[image]

**I would like to intersect the ZARR coordinates with the region ones. How can I achieve it?**

Comment: what's the chunking scheme of your zarr? If your chunks are including the areas you don't want, you won't get around loading and then discarding those areas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `rioxarray` and then clip to your region, very similar to [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/354798).

You will need to set the coordinate system. Assuming your data are given as standard lat/lon, this is epsg 4326 (see opening sentences [here](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/projections.html)). You may need to use `region_gdf.to_crs('epsg:4326')` to make sure that the coordinate systems are the same (or `set_crs` if it doesn't have a coordinate reference system already).

Once this formatting is done, you can use the `rio.clip` [method](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.raster_array.RasterArray.clip) and set `drop=True` to only keep the points in the region.

New lines below - it might not work exactly as written because I can't test it, but I think it should get you close.

```
import rioxarray 
zarr_ds.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="lon", y_dim="lat", inplace=True)
zarr_ds.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
zarr_ds_clipped = zarr_ds.rio.clip(region_gdf, drop=True)
```